# How to sum values returned from web Api Query?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sum, webapi

How to sum two values from two queries?

```
    var selectedValue = GetRadioSelectedValue($('#booleanA'));
    if (selectedValue == '1') {
        fetchQuantityA().done(function (data) {
            $("#qtyA").text(data['Qty_Part_A']);

        });
    } else

        $("#qtyA").text("0");



function fetchQuantityA() {
        return appAjax('Loading...', {
            type: "GET",
            url: `/table1?$select=Qty_Part_A`,
            contentType: "application/json"
        });

                var selectedValue = GetRadioSelectedValue($('#booleanB'));
                if (selectedValue == '1') {
                    fetchQuantityA().done(function (data) {
                        $("#qtyB").text(data['Qty_Part_B']);
            
                    });
                } else
            
                    $("#qtyB").text("0");
            
            
                };
               
               
function fetchQuantityB() {
        return appAjax('Loading...', {
            type: "GET",
            url: `/table2?$select=Qty_Part_B`,
            contentType: "application/json"
        })
        };
            function sumAmounts() {
                var sumZero = 0;
                var qtyA = $('#qtyA').val();
                var qtyB = $('#qtyB').val();
                $('#sumAmount').text(sumZero + qtyA + qtyB);
            };

            const resultHTML = `<td colspan="1" rowspan="1" class="clearfix cell">
            <div class="results"><span class="resultspan">totalQty</span>
            <div class="Qty">
            <h4 id="sumAmount"></h4>
            
            </div>
            </div>
            </td>
                `;
            
                $('[data-name="section"] tbody').find('tr').first().append(resultHTML);
```

Thanks for your help, I have tried a few options yet so far only managed to append a single value to display as html.

side note: I slimmed down the code to only what I think is important ‍♂️

also, I am very new to coding (is the above code JSON, JavaScript or jQuery - or a mix?)

tried `reduce` function unsuccessfully (incorrectly) - so hoping someone can steer me in the right direction to get the sum of two returned queries to show in html on the page!

Comment: Need to invoke `parseInt()` for `qtyA` and `qtyB`

Comment: Hi @lucumt - thanks for your reply. I am getting NaN on the page! is this right: `$('#sumAmount').text(sumZero + parseInt(qtyA) + parseInt(qtyB))`
also tried with radix:
`$('#sumAmount').text(sumZero + parseInt(qtyA,10) + parseInt(qtyB,10))`

Comment: [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is the programming language you're using above. [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) is a library; a collection of code meant to help you develop. All `$` and related references are from jQuery. [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/JSON) is a file format often used to interchange information over the internet. It resembles JS object literals (e.g. `{ "type": "GET" }`), hence its name.

Comment: Thanks @OskarGrosser  any hints as how to sum the returned properties?

Comment: Looking at this it looks like I haven't called the function 'sumAmounts'. Perhaps that's a good start.